# Ant run failure to load main

Tags: java, ant

I have oversimple Main.java file of next contents:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

The file was compiled by `ant` with next `compile` section in build.xml:

```
  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false"/>
  </target>
```

`Main.class` file has been created in `./build` directory.
Changing directory to `./build` and running`"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" Main` brings correct output.
However, running `ant -v run` from project root directory brungs next error:

```
run:
     [java] Executing 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
     [java] 'Main'
     [java]
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.
     [java] Error: Could not find or load main class Main
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

This is `run` section of `build.xml`:

```
  <target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="Main" fork="true">
    </java>
  </target>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You forgot to set the classpath to the build directory for the java task.

Comment: the `.class` file is not in the directory where `java` is being executed.... must add `${build.dir}` to the `java` task (as classpath, e.g. `classpath="${build.dir}"` or so [long time not using ant]) -- see suggested related question for example: [0 error running java in another dir from ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260846/error-running-java-in-another-dir-from-ant?rq=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user16320675 was correct.
This is a fix a `build.xml` `run` section fix:

```
<target name="run" depends="build">
  <java classname="${main.class}" classpath="${classpath}:${build.dir}">
  </java>
</target>
```